# Adding linking functionality to my XSLT in Drupal

Tags: php, xml, xslt, drupal-6, navigation

I have an XML feed that I have transformed into HTML for a dynamic Drupal page, courtesy of the nice users at [drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34109/populate-nodes-with-xml-data-via-xslt/34130#comment34719_34130).  The issue, however, is that the XML feed lists everything that could possibly ever need to be known, and my requirements are that each page renders a certain subset of information.

Essentially, it is a presentation schedule that needs to be broken down.

My example feed is as follows:

```
<track name="Track 1">
  <session name="Session 1" starttime="2012-06-06 10:45" endtime="2012-06-06 12:45">
    <presentation name="Presentation 1">
       <author>Name 1</author>
       <author>Name 2</author>
       <abstract>summary of this presentation</abstract>
    </presentation>
    <presentation name="Presentation 2">
      ...presentation info
    </presentation>
  </session>

  <session name="Session 2" starttime="2012-06-06 10:45" endtime="2012-06-06 12:45">
    <presentation name="Presentation 3">
      ...presentation info
    </presentation>
    <presentation name="Presentation 4">
      ...presentation info
    </presentation>
  </session>

  <session name="Session 3" starttime="2012-06-07 08:45" endtime="2012-06-07 10:45">
    <presentation name="Presentation 5">
      ...presentation info
    </presentation>
    <presentation name="Presentation 6">
      ...presentation info
    </presentation>
  </session>
</track>
```

So, as you can see, I get all information for this entire proceeding.  Every single track, session, and presentation all in one feed.  As of right now, I can parse that into a dynamic page without any issue.

Essentially, here is what I would like to get it to (ignoring the parsing of the dateTime...I have that in place already):

```
<h2>Track 1</h2>
<h3>Session 1</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="presentation-1.html">Presentation 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="presentation-2.html">Presentation 2</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>Sessoin 2</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="presentation-3.html">Presentation 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="presentation-4.html">Presentation 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then, clicking one of the presentation links would take you to a new page:

```
<h2>Presentation 1</h2>
<p>Presented by Name 1, Name 2</p>
<p>summary of this presentation</p>
```

So, I have two issues here ... I don't exactly know how to break up a feed in this manner, and this must be done within a Drupal 6 module.  I am just showing a snippet of a sample feed...because the feed that I do get is quite large, and must be broken up in this manner.

The Drupal code that I have is as follows:

```
function _xml_import_generate()
{
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'xml_import');
  $xsl = new DOMDocument();
  $xsl->load("{$path}/xml_import.xsl");

  $xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 
  $xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load("myfeed.xml");

  return (string) $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
}
```

Comment: can we see the XSL you already have to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. For the first page you want**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="track">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="pTrack" select=
         "count(preceding-sibling::track) +1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="session">
  <xsl:param name="pTrack"/>
   <h3><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h3>
   <ul>
     <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="pTrack" select="$pTrack"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pSess" select=
            "count(preceding-sibling::session) +1"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="presentation">
  <xsl:param name="pTrack"/>
  <xsl:param name="pSess" />
  <li>
    <a href=
    "presentation.html?track={$pTrack}&amp;sess={$pSess}&amp;pr={position()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </a>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<conference>
    <track name="Track 1">
      <session name="Session 1" starttime="2012-06-06 10:45" endtime="2012-06-06 12:45">
        <presentation name="Presentation 1">
           <author>Name 1</author>
           <author>Name 2</author>
           <abstract>summary of this presentation</abstract>
        </presentation>
        <presentation name="Presentation 2">
          ...presentation info
        </presentation>
      </session>

      <session name="Session 2" starttime="2012-06-06 10:45" endtime="2012-06-06 12:45">
        <presentation name="Presentation 3">
          ...presentation info
        </presentation>
        <presentation name="Presentation 4">
          ...presentation info
        </presentation>
      </session>

      <session name="Session 3" starttime="2012-06-07 08:45" endtime="2012-06-07 10:45">
        <presentation name="Presentation 5">
          ...presentation info
        </presentation>
        <presentation name="Presentation 6">
          ...presentation info
        </presentation>
      </session>
    </track>
</conference>
```

**this useful result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <h2>Track 1</h2>
   <h3>Session 1</h3>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=1&amp;pr=1">Presentation 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=1&amp;pr=2">Presentation 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <h3>Session 2</h3>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=2&amp;pr=1">Presentation 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=2&amp;pr=2">Presentation 4</a></li>
   </ul>
   <h3>Session 3</h3>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=3&amp;pr=1">Presentation 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="presentation.html?track=1&amp;sess=3&amp;pr=2">Presentation 6</a></li>
   </ul>
</html>
```

---

**II. The second page:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="track" select="1"/>
 <xsl:param name="sess" select="1"/>
 <xsl:param name="pr" select="1"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <html>
       <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "track[position()=$track]
                  /session[position()=$sess]
                      /presentation[position()=$pr]"/>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="presentation">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
  <p>Presented by <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="author"/>
  </p>
  <p><xsl:copy-of select="abstract/node()"/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="author">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <h2>Presentation 1</h2>
   <p>Presented by Name 1, Name 2</p>
   <p>summary of this presentation</p>
</html>
```

**Do note**:

Whenever the end-user clicks on a link on the first page, the web server must process this web-request and must invoke the second transformation, passing to it the external/global parameters, whose values it must properly set from the corresponding query-string parameters.

Comment: So I would have to have PHP set the $track/$sess/$pr variables in the XSL?

Comment: Yes, with whatever programming language you are working -- I don't know Drupal and it wouldn't be surprizing if Drupal provides such capability. In case you can use C# and XslCompiledTransform, I can show you how to specify and pass external parameters to the transformation.

Comment: This page should be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I've noticed that each presentation has a completely unique ID associated with each.  Is it possible to jump straight to that node without using the position() call?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: never mind, got it (//presentation[@id=$p])

Comment: @espais: Or one could use `<xsl:key>` and the `key()` function, which adds speed if more than one search is performed -- however I guess that in this particular case only a single search is performed -- therefore `presentation[@id=$p]` is OK.